# dataframe Can I extract the pure values in the list properly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am currently a Python self-educating beginner.

```
for index, row in df_price.iterrows():                    
    prod_weight = prod_weight = prod_data.loc[prod_data['sku'] == row['sku']]['weight'].item
```

------result --------------------------------------

```
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.item of 18066    0.2
Name: weight, dtype: float64>
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.item of 18063    0.1
Name: weight, dtype: float64>
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.item of 18064    0.1
Name: weight, dtype: float64>
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.item of Series([], Name: weight, dtype: float64)>
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.item of 18062    0.1
Name: weight, dtype: float64>
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.item of 18058    0.1
Name: weight, dtype: float64>
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.item of 18059    0.1

---------------------------------------------------------
```

The result I want is:

```
1.0
0.2
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
...
0.5
0.6
0.3
```

so,I changed the code as follows.

```
prod_weight = prod_data.loc[prod_data['sku'] == row['sku']]['weight'].item()
```

-------------result--------------------------------

```
1.0
0.2
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
...
0.5
0.6
0.3
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "D:/python_project/price_reviser/price_reviser.py", line 58, in 
>           prod_weight = prod_data.loc[prod_data['sku'] == row['sku']]['weight'].item()
>         File "C:\Users\tlsdy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py",
>   line 719, in item
>           return self.values.item()
>       ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

So I changed the code again as shown below.

```
prod_weight = prod_data.loc[prod_data['sku'] == row['sku']]['weight'].values

-------------result--------------------------------
[1.0]
[0.2]
[0.1]
[0.1]
[0.1]
[0.1]
[0.1]
...
[0.5]
[0.6]
[0.3]
```

So I changed the code again as shown below.

```
prod_weight = re.sub('\[|''\]|''\'|', '', str(prod_data.loc[prod_data['sku'] == row['sku']]['weight'].values))
```

--------------result-------

```
1.
0.2
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
0.1
...
0.5
0.6
0.3
```

but,

```
1.0 --> 1.
2.0 --> 2.
```

How can I extract it properly?
How can I extract it properly?
How can I extract it properly?
How can I extract it properly?
How can I extract it properly?

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of the DataFrame (and column data types) to know what the source data looks like? In your first attempt you are simply listing the uncalled function (`item`), not executing it. In your second attempt you run up against a Numpy novelty regarding Numpy arrays. Your third attempt seems to give you what you want (except producing a Numpy array instead of a float, I'm guessing). Your last attempt ... don't dare to do that again, do not use regular expressions (here) :).

Comment: @susim can you just print df.head() (all necessary columns atlest)

Comment: `prod_weight = prod_weight = ...` are you sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in df_price.iterrows():
    try:        
        prod_weight= prod_data.loc[prod_data['sku'] == row['sku']]['weight'].item()
    except:
        prod_weight= prod_data.loc[prod_data['sku'] == row['sku']]['weight']
```

TRY this.

The error `ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar` is because .item() works only on series/dataframe datatypes. and if you try to do any scalar.item()  it will throw this error